# Warning when renaming column of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, warnings

I execute the following code on the Python DataFrame "restaurants":

```
 italian_restaurants = restaurants[restaurants['Cuisine']=='Italian']
italian_restaurants.rename(columns = {'Total restaurants':'Italian restaurants'}, inplace = True)
```

And the response is the following *warning*:

```
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:4125: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  return super().rename(
```

How can I rewrite the code to avoid the warning? The problem seems to verse around the idea that I am copying the slice into a new DataFrame, but I cannot find the solution.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Use `italian_restaurants = restaurants[restaurants['Cuisine']=='Italian'].copy()`

Comment: Thank you! It solved the problem